# Simple inquiry: Why does it say this variable is undefined?

Tags: python, variables, undefined

I'm quite new to Python. I'm using the latest version. The code I'm working with is below:

```
def tts():
    print('(0) Input a new list')
    print('(1) Print the current list')

    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    if choice == 0:
        newList = eval(input('Enter a new list of prices: '))
        tts();

    elif choice == 1:
        return newList
```

So, I start by running the function tts(). It prints what it's supposed to and prompts me for input. I type 0, and input a list, such as [20,10,30]. After hitting enter at that point, shouldn't the variable newList now be assigned to the list I input? It doesn't seem to work. If I later type newList in the Shell, it says that newList isn't defined. For the same reason presumably, if I later select 1 as my choice, it will say newList isn't defined.

I would greatly appreciate some advice. I'm getting quite frustrated and I suspect this is a very trivial issue I'm just not aware of.

Comment: fyi `eval` is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `tts()` recursively (why?), and `newList` is a local variable. When you make the recursive call, `newList` is not defined in the new stack frame.

It would probably be easiest to reorganise your code into a loop instead of recursion. Then, you won't have a new stack frame and `newList` will still be accessible.

Comment: Ok I think I've discovered my deeper misunderstanding. I've tried to make this as minimalist as possible. Consider this code:

    def test():
    t = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
    if t == 0:
        testing();

    def testing():
        a = 2
        return a

If I run test() and then enter 0 when prompted in Shell, nothing at all is returned. Just a blank line. Why is this? Shouldn't it return 2?

Comment: Crap, I can't type code in the comments? Sorry, I'm not trying to be lazy or rude, but can you decipher it anyway? If not I'll clarify.

Comment: To clarify anyway:

Shouldn't it return 2, because it calls testing(), which is written to return a, which equals 2?

Comment: I think you want `if t == 0: return testing()` otherwise you're not returning a value from `test()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your "newList" is defined in the if statement and it's being returned in the ELSE statement. So if it makes it into the elif, then it never was created.